# Password field is disabled in Icedtea

Tags: java, icedtea

Password Field is disabled when I start my "**jnlp**" program using **IcedTea**. How to enable password field so I can login?

[image]

Comment: Please provide OS & release details; your picture doesn't seem to be a Lubuntu release

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: I would apply upgrades to your system & try again.  A fully updated *bionic* system will report itself as 18.04.5, not 18.04.3 (so you're more than 12 months behind in upgraded packages & security fixes; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date for .4, but installed systems upgraded to it before that date, and likewise the .5).

Comment: I have upgraded my OS, Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic. but the problem remain in its place.

Comment: Why does your shown picture not match your tagged OS?

Comment: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that only days ago reached it's EOL.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses  See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note only supported releases are on-topic here